# What's the usual best way to lock a collection?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Suppose I have a collection of items which is read and written accross a multithreaded application. When it comes to apply an algorithm over some items I thing of different ways to acquire a lock.

By locking during the entire operation:

```
lock(collection)
{
    for each thing in things
    {
        get the item from collection that matches thing
        do stuff with item
    }
}
```

By locking on demand:

```
for each thing in things
{
    lock(collection)
    {
        get the item from collection that matches thing
    }
    do stuff with item
}
```

Or by locking on demand to get a thread safe collection of items to process later, thus having collection locked for a smaller amount of time:

```
Items items
for each thing in things
{
    lock(collection)
    {
        get the item from collection that matches thing
    }
    items.Add(item)
}
for each item in items
{
    do stuff with item
}
```

I know it may eventually depend on the actual algorithm applied to each item, but what would you do? I am using C++, but I am pretty sure it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Double Check lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern which involves separate field for the collection/field under the lock.

Also it worth to take a look at the [Readers-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock) technique which allows reading whilst an other thread updating a collection

**EDIT:** 
As David Heffernan mentioned take a look at the [The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) discussion

Comment: Regardless of this technique, what would you do in my case?

Comment: See updated answer, idea is to introduce separate field/variable along with a collection and lock this particular field insteat of locking of a collection or each element (former is a mess!)

Comment: Don't recommend double checked locking without discussion of the "double checked locking is broken" declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In a multi-threaded setting, with thread reading and writing, your first and second examples have different meaning. Your third example could have yet another meaning if "do something with item" interacts with other threads.

You need to decide what you want the code to do before deciding how to do it.

Comment: The "do something with item" will interact with other threads but not the ones that uses my collection of items.

Answer (score 0):

Lock acquisition and release are expensive.  I would lock over the collection rather than each individual element in a loop.  It makes sense if the entire operation needs to be atomic.